# Where are my OneDrive for Business files?

Tags: online-accounts, microsoft

Ubuntu 17.10 here.

I added my school OneDrive account and it says that my mail and documents are now being synced. OK? So where are they?

My google drive is syncing just fine, but my OneDrive isn't even giving me something to troubleshoot because I don't see any difference. How do I sync my onedrive account?

Answer (score 0):

I know of one available client for OneDrive (Personal, not Business, as far as I know, but it might also work for Business), which is available in the 18.04 Universe repository and I believe is also available in 17.10. However, it is CLI-only and has no GUI. My only experience with it was on 17.10 and it was syncing my entire OneDrive account's worth of data. I have not fine-tuned it using the reference information given on the author's GitHub page, though. I decided to use DropBox instead, but the built-in Google sync seems to work well, too. I think this client could work for you, but will require a bit of fine-tuning. This is the Github page for the client, and best of luck!

http://skilion.github.io/onedrive/

Answer (score 0):

> I know of one available client for OneDrive (Personal, not Business, as far as I know, but it might also work for Business), which is available in the 18.04 Universe repository and I believe is also available in 17.10. However, it is CLI-only and has no GUI. My only experience with it was on 17.10 and it was syncing my entire OneDrive account's worth of data. I have not fine-tuned it using the reference information given on the author's GitHub page, though. I decided to use DropBox instead, but the built-in Google sync seems to work well, too. I think this client could work for you, but will require a bit of fine-tuning. This is the Github page for the client, and best of luck!
>
> http://skilion.github.io/onedrive/

The 'skilion' client was abandoned in 2018, and all development moved here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

To install the client correctly on Ubuntu you have 2 options:

1. If using Ubuntu 18.x and below - compile from source
2. If using Ubuntu 19.x and above - Use the Ubuntu PPA

Do not install the client from 'Universe' as this will install old versions of the client.

**To compile from source:**

1. Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libsqlite3-dev pkg-config git curl
```

2. Install the compiler

```
curl -fsS https://dlang.org/install.sh | bash -s dmd
```

3. Activate the compiler

```
source ~/dlang/dmd-2.093.1/activate
```

4. Clone the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive.git
```

5. Build the client

```
cd onedrive; ./configure; make clean; make;
```

6. Install

```
sudo make install
```

**To install using the Ubuntu PPA**

1. Add the Ubuntu PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yann1ck/onedrive
sudo apt-get update
```

2. Install 'onedrive' from the Ubuntu PPA

```
sudo apt install onedrive
```

For further details refer to:

- Install Guide: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md
- Usage Guide: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md

For issues or support, open an issue ticket on GitHub